# HtmlViewService in OBIEE Web Service API is not rendering report (it's only showing spinning loader)

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, obiee

I have a Java application that leverages the OBIEE Web Service API to consume data from the BI Server. I am able to XMLViewService and the WebCatalogService just fine, but I can't quite get the HtmlViewService to properly render a report in the Java app. The report just shows the spinning loader, but never actually renders the report. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that the Java app and the BI Server are on different domains. This is what the API documentation says:

**In situations where Oracle BI Web Services and the third-party Web server do not  belong to the same Domain Name Service (DNS) domain, users may get JavaScript errors related to browser security constraints for cross-domain scripting. To avoid these issues, use the setBridge() method to modify callback URLs to point to the third-party Web server. Be aware that a Web component executed by the third-party Web server to re-route requests to Oracle BI Web Services is not provided. This function would need to be fulfilled by the third-party application.**

Several years ago, I did this same type of integration using .NET/C# and ran in the the same issue because the .NET app and the BI Server were on different domains. As a result, I had to create an HTTP Handler (.ashx file) as well as use the setBridge() method to to solve the issue.

The challenge that I'm having is that I can't find a servlet bridge example for Java. And I'm not too confident in porting the .NET/.ASHX code to a Java servlet/bridge. Does anyone have any code examples or direction they could provide to point me in the right direction?  Here's a snippet of code to show you what I'm doing to pull back the report data:

```
    // define report path
    ReportRef reportRef = new ReportRef();
    reportRef.setReportPath(reportFolder + "/" + reportName);

    // set page params
    StartPageParams pageParams = new StartPageParams(); 
    pageParams.setDontUseHttpCookies(true);

    // set report params
    String pageId = htmlService.startPage(pageParams, sawSessionId);
    String reportId = pageId + reportName;
    htmlService.addReportToPage(pageId, reportId, reportRef, null, null, null, sawSessionId);

    // get report html
    StringBuffer reportHtml = new StringBuffer(); 
    reportHtml.append(htmlService.getHtmlForReport(pageId, reportId, sawSessionId)); 

    // return html
    return reportHtml.toString();
```

**This is the error that is coming back in the browser:**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myobiserver.com/analytics/saw.dll?ajaxGo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myjavaapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Per requested, here is my .NET/.ASHX bridge:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

/*
This is a ASP.NET handler that handles communication 
between the SharePoint site and OracleBI.
It will be deployed to: 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\OracleBI
*/

public class OracleBridge: IHttpHandler
{
  public   bool IsReusable {get{return true;}}
  public OracleBridge()
  {
  }
  string getServer()
  {
      string strServer = "http://<enter-domain>/analytics/saw.dll";
     int index = strServer.LastIndexOf("/");//split off saw.dll
     if (index >=0)
        return strServer.Substring(0,index+1);
     else
        return strServer;
  }
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
     HttpWebRequest req = forwardRequest(context);
     forwardResponse(context,req);
  }
  private HttpWebRequest forwardRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
     string strURL = makeURL(context);
     HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
     req.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;
     NameValueCollection   headers = context.Request.Headers;
     req.Accept  = headers.Get("Accept");
     req.Expect = headers.Get("Expect");
     req.ContentType = headers.Get("Content-Type");
     string strModifiedSince = headers.Get("If-Modified-Since");
     if (strModifiedSince != null && strModifiedSince.Length != 0)
        req.IfModifiedSince =  DateTime.Parse(strModifiedSince);
     req.Referer = headers.Get("Referer");
     req.UserAgent = headers.Get("User-Agent");    
     if (!req.Method.Equals("GET"))
     {
        CopyStreams(context.Request.InputStream,req.GetRequestStream());
     }
     return req;
  }

  private void forwardResponse(HttpContext context, HttpWebRequest req)
  {
     HttpWebResponse resp =null;
     try
     {
        resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
     }
     catch(WebException e)
     {
        resp =  (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
     }
     context.Response.StatusCode = (int)resp.StatusCode;

     for (int i = 0; i < resp.Cookies.Count; i++)
     {
         Cookie c = resp.Cookies[i];
         HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie(c.Name, c.Value);
         hc.Path = c.Path;
         hc.Domain = getServer();
         context.Response.Cookies.Add(hc);
     }
     context.Response.ContentType = resp.ContentType;
     CopyStreams(resp.GetResponseStream(), context.Response.OutputStream);
  }


  private string makeURL(HttpContext context)
  {
     string strQuery = context.Request.Url.Query;
     string[] arrParams = strQuery.Split('?','&');
     StringBuilder resultingParams = new StringBuilder();
     string strURL=null;
     foreach(string strParam in arrParams )
     { 
        string[] arrNameValue = strParam.Split('=');
        if (!arrNameValue[0].Equals("RedirectURL"))
        {
           if (strParam.Length != 0)
           {
              if (resultingParams.Length != 0)
                 resultingParams.Append("&");
              resultingParams.Append(strParam);
           }
        }
        else if (arrNameValue.Length >1)
           strURL = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(arrNameValue[1]);
     }

     if (strURL ==null)
        throw new Exception("Invalid URL format. requestURL parameter is missing");
     String sAppendChar = strURL.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?";
     if (strURL.StartsWith("http:") || strURL.StartsWith("https:"))
     {
         String tmpURL = strURL + sAppendChar + resultingParams.ToString();
         return tmpURL;
     }
     else
     {
         String tmpURL = getServer() + strURL + sAppendChar + resultingParams.ToString();
         return tmpURL;
     }
  }

  private void CopyStreams(Stream inStr,Stream outStr)
  {
     byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
     try
     {
        do
        {
           int iRead = inStr.Read(buf,0,4096);
           if (iRead == 0)
              break;
           outStr.Write(buf,0,iRead);
        }
        while (true);
     }
     finally
     {
        outStr.Close();
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the BridgeServlet from link (http://pastebin.com/NibVnBLb) posted in previous answer did not work for us. In our web portal, embedding Oracle BI dashboard using BridgeServlet above, redirected us to OBI login page and console log showed incorrect resources(js/css) web links (local URL instead of OBIEE URL's).

Instead we used this class (with some minor adjustments) https://gist.github.com/rafaeltuelho/9376341#file-obieehttpservletbridge-java.

Tested with Java 11, Oracle Business Intelligence 12.2.1.4.0, WSDL v12 of OBIEE (http://OBIEE-server:port/analytics/saw.dll/wsdl/v12), with SSO disabled.

Here it is the **BridgeServlet** class:

```
package com.abs.bi;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class OBIEEBridge
 */
public class BridgeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BridgeServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            this.processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            this.processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpURLConnection urlCon = forwardRequest(request);
        forwardResponse(response, urlCon);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private String decodeURL(HttpServletRequest request) {

        StringBuffer bufURL = new StringBuffer("");

        Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

        String[] arrURL = params.get("RedirectURL");
        String strURL = arrURL == null || arrURL.length == 0 ? null : arrURL[0];
        bufURL.append(strURL);

        int nQIndex = strURL.lastIndexOf('?');

        if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
            bufURL.append(((nQIndex >= 0) ? "&" : "?"));
            Set<String> keys = params.keySet();
            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    String strKey = it.next();

                    if (strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("RedirectURL")) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String strEncodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(strKey, "UTF-8");

                    String[] paramValues = params.get(strKey);
                    for (String paramValue : paramValues) {
                        bufURL.append(strEncodedKey);
                        bufURL.append("=");
                        bufURL.append(URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8"));
                        bufURL.append("&");
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            bufURL.deleteCharAt(bufURL.length() - 1);
        }

        return bufURL.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private HttpURLConnection forwardRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        String strURL = decodeURL(request);

        String[] arrURL = strURL.split("&", 2);
        String baseURL = arrURL[0];

        URL url = new URL(baseURL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        String strMethod = request.getMethod();
        con.setRequestMethod(strMethod);

        Enumeration<String> en = request.getHeaderNames();
        String strHeader;
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            strHeader = en.nextElement();

            String strHeaderValue = request.getHeader(strHeader);
            con.setRequestProperty(strHeader, strHeaderValue);
        }

        // is not a HTTP GET request
        if (strMethod.compareTo("GET") != 0) {

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);

            DataOutputStream forwardStream = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

            try {
                String urlParameters = arrURL[1];
                forwardStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                forwardStream.flush();
            } finally {
                forwardStream.close();
            }
        }

        return con;
    }

    private void forwardResponse(HttpServletResponse response, HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {

        int nContentLen = -1;
        String strKey;
        String strValue;

        try {

            response.setStatus(con.getResponseCode());

            for (int i = 1; true; ++i) {
                strKey = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
                strValue = con.getHeaderField(i);

                if (strKey == null) {
                    break;
                }

                if (strKey.equals("Content-Length")) {
                    nContentLen = Integer.parseInt(con.getHeaderField(i));
                    continue;
                }

                if (strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Connection") || strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Server")
                        || strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Transfer-Encoding") || strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Length")) {
                    continue; // skip certain headers
                }

                if (strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie")) {
                    String[] cookieStr1 = strValue.split(";");
                    String[] cookieStr2 = cookieStr1[0].split("=");
//                  String[] cookieStr3 = cookieStr1[1].split("=");

                    /*
                     * Change the Set-Cookie HTTP Header to remove the 'path' attribute. Thus the
                     * browser can accept the ORA_BIPS_NQID cookie from Oracle BI Server
                     */

                    Cookie c = new Cookie(cookieStr2[0], cookieStr2[1]);
                    c.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(c);

                } else {
                    response.setHeader(strKey, strValue);

                }

            }

            copyStreams(con.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream(), nContentLen);

        } finally {
            response.getOutputStream().close();
            con.getInputStream().close();
        }
    }

    private void copyStreams(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream forwardStream, int nContentLen) throws IOException {

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int nCount = 0;
        int nBytesToRead = 1024;
        int nTotalCount = 0;

        do {
            if (nContentLen != -1)
                nBytesToRead = nContentLen - nTotalCount > 1024 ? 1024 : nContentLen - nTotalCount;

            if (nBytesToRead == 0)
                break;

            // try to read some bytes from src stream
            nCount = inputStream.read(buf, 0, nBytesToRead);

            if (nCount < 0)
                break;

            nTotalCount += nCount;

            // try to write some bytes in target stream
            forwardStream.write(buf, 0, nCount);

        } while (true);
    }

}
```

**AbsServiceUtils** which contains SAWSessionService and HtmlViewService web service calls to Oracle BI server:

```
package com.abs.bi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;

import oracle.bi.web.soap.AuthResult;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.HtmlViewService;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.HtmlViewServiceSoap;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.ReportHTMLLinksMode;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.ReportHTMLOptions;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.ReportRef;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.SAWLocale;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.SAWSessionParameters;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.SAWSessionService;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.SAWSessionServiceSoap;
import oracle.bi.web.soap.StartPageParams;

public class AbsServiceUtils {

    private AbsServiceUtils() {
    }

    public static URL buildWsdlUrl() throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL(IAbsService.BASEWSDLURL);
    }

    public static void writeBiContent(HttpServletRequest request, JspWriter out, String biReport) throws IOException {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
        Locale userLocale = request.getLocale();
        String bridgeServletContextPath = request.getContextPath() + "/bridgeservlet";
        String reportHtml = writeBiContent(biReport, userAgent, userLocale, bridgeServletContextPath);
        if (out != null) {
            out.println(reportHtml);
        }
    }

    public static String writeBiContent(String biReport, String userAgent, Locale userLocale,
            String bridgeServletContextPath) throws MalformedURLException {
        HtmlViewService htmlViewService = new HtmlViewService(buildWsdlUrl());
        HtmlViewServiceSoap htmlClient = htmlViewService.getHtmlViewService();

        SAWSessionService sAWSessionService = new SAWSessionService(buildWsdlUrl());
        SAWSessionServiceSoap myPort = sAWSessionService.getSAWSessionServiceSoap();

        SAWSessionParameters sessionparams = new SAWSessionParameters();
        sessionparams.setUserAgent(userAgent);
        SAWLocale sawlocale = new SAWLocale();
        sawlocale.setLanguage(userLocale.getLanguage());
        sawlocale.setCountry(userLocale.getCountry());
        sessionparams.setLocale(sawlocale);
        sessionparams.setAsyncLogon(false);

        AuthResult result = myPort.logonex(IAbsService.BIUSERNAME, IAbsService.BIPASSWORD, sessionparams);
        String sessionID = result.getSessionID();
        List<String> keepAliveSessionList = new ArrayList<>(1);
        keepAliveSessionList.add(sessionID);
        myPort.keepAlive(keepAliveSessionList);

        StartPageParams spparams = new StartPageParams();
        spparams.setDontUseHttpCookies(true);
        String pageID = htmlClient.startPage(spparams, sessionID);

        /**
         * This method will set the path to the servlet which will act like a bridge to
         * retrieve all the OBIEE resources like the javascript, CSS and the report.
         */
        if (bridgeServletContextPath != null) {
            htmlClient.setBridge(bridgeServletContextPath, sessionID);
        }

        ReportHTMLOptions htmlOptions = new ReportHTMLOptions();
        htmlOptions.setEnableDelayLoading(false);
        htmlOptions.setLinkMode(ReportHTMLLinksMode.IN_PLACE.value());

        ReportRef reportref = new ReportRef();
        reportref.setReportPath(IAbsService.BIROOTPATH + biReport);

        StartPageParams startpageparams = new StartPageParams();
        startpageparams.setDontUseHttpCookies(false);

        htmlClient.addReportToPage(pageID, biReport.replace(" ", ""), reportref, null, null, htmlOptions, sessionID);

        String reportHtml = htmlClient.getHeadersHtml(pageID, sessionID);
        reportHtml = reportHtml + htmlClient.getHtmlForReport(pageID, biReport.replace(" ", ""), sessionID);
        reportHtml = reportHtml + htmlClient.getCommonBodyHtml(pageID, sessionID);

        return reportHtml;
    }

}
```

**IAbsService**:

```
package com.abs.bi;

public interface IAbsService {
    public static final String BASEWSDLURL = "http://<OracleBIServer:port>/analytics/saw.dll/wsdl/v12";
    public static final String BIUSERNAME = "USER";
    public static final String BIPASSWORD = "PASS";
    public static final String BIROOTPATH = "/shared/sharedfolder/";
    public static final String BIREPORTNAME = "report";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the link http://pastebin.com/NibVnBLb to check out the bridge code for java. Hope this might be helful.

Comment: I'm having three issues that aren't allowing me to Build and I can't figure out a fix: 1) "HttpProxyServlet.getHeaders(request, hashtable);" is throwing "cannot be reolved" 2) "URLConnection httpConnection = urlconn.openConnection();" is throwing "is undefined for the type URL" 2) "com.abs.util.GetPost.rewriteHeaders(httpConnection, response);" is throwing "cannot be resolved" ... Lastly, where do I plug in the URL for the base URL for the BI server? (which was "string strServer = "http://<enter-domain>/analytics/saw.dll";" in the original C# code)? Thank you!

Comment: I figured out bullet #2 above by using URLConnection from java.net. Still working on #1 and #3.

Comment: I missed out an other link related to this code. check out this link http://pastebin.com/ndVt3HBu for the code leveraging the services. I hope it is not required to give the base url of the BI server in the bridge code. I will update you if I am able to get a solution for #1 issue.

Comment: I am sorry about the last comment. It was my issue, user agent that I assigned was wrong. Anyways even after sending the right user agent a call is finally made to http://<BI server dmoain>/analytics/saw.dll?getReportXmlFromSearchID and after that 
localhost:57169/… Server IP>%3a<Port>%2fanalytics%2fsaw.dll%2fpages/common/ajaxloggedin.html is called. And the login screen comes up. Not sure why this issue is happening. It would be greatful if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same issue, as the ajaxloggedin.html is being called. Not sure why. But can you look at my comment above and the issue I was having with #1 and #3? I wonder if the issue has to do with the bridge. As I said, I've had to comment out a couple lines of code in the bridge, which might be what is causing the problem. If you figure it out, please let me know! Can you also send me your updated bridge servlet code? Thank you.

Comment: If you could also include all your imports at the top of your bridge servlet, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: But Josh, I dont have much experience with java. I am integrating obiee with my asp.net app. I will anyways check out the imports for the bridge servlet and I will update you when I find it.

Comment: I found an other link suggesting some important points to be remembered while integrating with java app. Check this out  http://skzine.net/info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=54:obiee-integration-with-websphere-portal&catid=61:websphere-portal-integration&Itemid=41

Comment: So, the Java servlet you provided for me, was that something you wrote or did you use a tool to do it? Also, I'm wondering if there is a solution that works for both of us, because I was able to render the report HTML using .NET (with the bridge code I provided) but it was on OBI 10g.

Comment: I had the issue with the spinning loader on the .NET side, but the ASHX bridge solved the issue.